# Macro to open all PPT files

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I created the following macro to open all ppt files in a certain map

```
Sub openAllPPT()
    Dim strCurrentFile As String
    Dim strFileSpec As String

    strFileSpec = "C:\Documents and Settings\aa471714\Desktop\Nieuwe map*.ppt"
    strCurrentFile = Dir$(strFileSpec)

    While Len(strCurrentFile) > 0
          Presentations.Open (strCurrentFile)
          strCurrentFile = Dir$
    Wend

End Sub
```

When I run it I do see anything opening up though. Anybody clue on what I'm missing?

Comment: Try `Presentations.Open FileName:=strCurrentFile, WithWindow:=True`

Comment: Sure the loop is entered? Tried adding the path to the file as strCurrentFile is the filename sans path

Comment: You code is archaic. Try working with the FileSystemObject. Also, replace the While..Wend with a Do While..Loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dir returns only the file name, not the full path to the file.
Try this instead:

```
Sub openAllPPT()

    Dim strCurrentFile As String
    Dim strFileSpec As String
    Dim strDirectory As String

    strDirectory = "C:\Documents and Settings\aa471714\Desktop\"
    strFileSpec = "Nieuwe map*.ppt"

    strCurrentFile = Dir$(strDirectory & strFileSpec)

    While Len(strCurrentFile) > 0
          'Presentations.Open (strDirectory & strCurrentFile)
          Debug.Print strDirectory & strCurrentFile
          strCurrentFile = Dir$
    Wend

End Sub
```